# ActiveRecord query help. Finding the latest record from each group

Tags: activerecord

So I have an orders table that looks like this:

[image]

Where ledger_id is a uuid and version is a timestamp.

There could be many orders per `ledger_id`. This is a denormalized table btw, used to keep track of orders and their progression through processing FWIW.

If a couple ledger_ids come in and we want the latest order for each `ledger_id`, what's the ActiveRecord query that will get us this?

I feel like I'm close. I have this:

`orders = Order.where(ledger_id: ledger_ids).group(:ledger_id, :id).having('version = MIN(version)').first`

where `ledger_ids` is an array of 1 or more ledger uuids.

But this gives us an error:

```
:StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "orders.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT  "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."ledger_id" ...
                ^
: SELECT  "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."ledger_id" = $1 GROUP BY "orders"."ledger_id" ORDER BY "orders"."id" ASC LIMIT $2
```

Anyone know of a solution?

Comment: Did you cut the last line of the error that shows the actual sql query that causes the error? Why those ...? Put the whole error

Comment: I think `Order.select("DISTINCT ON(ledger_id)*").order("ledger_id, version DESC")` works but I have no idea why. What is that doing? Is it right? Why do I need the `ledger_id` in the `order` clause?